# Seems Terraform GitLab provider does not provide Slack/Teams webhook URL anymore

Tags: gitlab, terraform-provider-gitlab

Currently we are using Terraform to "check" (via `terraform plan -detailed-exitcode`) whether current GitLab resources
comply with our specification (described in `*.tf` files).

Since 1st of March (2023), our nightly pipeline run executing these checks fails due to the fact that Terraform GitLab Provider (or even GitLab.com's API
server) does **not** "see" configured Slack/Teams webhook URLs anymore.

This yields to the behaviour that **repeated issuance** of `terraform apply` constantly succeeds, but **each** invocation
**also** states that these webhook URLs needs to get changed:

```bash
$ terraform apply
[...]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.GitlabProject.gitlab_service_microsoft_teams.[...] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "gitlab_service_microsoft_teams" "[...]" {
        id                           = "[...]"
      ~ webhook                      = (sensitive value)
        # (15 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.GitlabProject.gitlab_service_slack.[...] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "gitlab_service_slack" "[...]" {
        id                           = "[...]"
      ~ webhook                      = (sensitive value)
        # (23 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

[...]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 2 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Issuing `terraform apply` again and again comes up with exactly the same output **each time**!

As Terraform State contains **empty** value of `webhook` field ...

```bash
$ terraform state pull | grep '"webhook":'
            "webhook": "",
            "webhook": "",
```

... I suspect that either Terraform Provider fails in handling this field, or GitLab.com's API server does not provide
this field's value anymore (since end of February 2023). Searched for information regarding possible changes on this topic in GitLab's API, but found none.

By the way, mentioned webhook URLs are set **correctly** on our GitLab projects ... they are visible on our project's
GitLab page ... and we still receive notifications on our Slack/Teams channels (not only regarding failing pipeline
runs I've described at the beginning) ... ;-)

So it seems to me to be a Terraform Provider and/or GitLab.com API server issue.

Any ideas/hints on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new resource [integration_microsoft_teams](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/integration_microsoft_teams) available, which solves the reported issue.